# Trigger input onchange while input is active/focus

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am trying to get the submit button of a form to change colour when all required field are set.

I can do it, by doing this:

```
if(window.addEventListener) {
        document.getElementById('login_form_form').addEventListener('change', loginSubmitOrange, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent){
        document.getElementById('login_form_form').attachEvent("onchange", loginSubmitOrange);
    }
```

The function checks to see that the required fields are set and, if they are, changes the colour of the submit button.

It only does it after the field is click away from.

How do I do it so that the function is triggered while the user is typing? Not after the user has clicked away from the last required field?

I have been told, in other places, that it's impossible but I am sure I've seen it before.

Also, no jQuery please; I know I'm being a hipster but I would like to know everything from scratch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `onkeypress` event and I think you should be able to achieve what you want to.

Answer (score 0):

By using a key event instead of `onchange`

```
var elem = document.getElementById('login_form_form');

if(window.addEventListener) {
    elem.addEventListener('keyup', loginSubmitOrange, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent){
    elem.attachEvent("onkeyup", loginSubmitOrange);
}
```